# Allow customer to send me email

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, mailing

I'm bulding website where I want to allow future customers to send me an email. I'm using Node.js to handle sending and thought SendGrid would be good solution. There's actually problem, because SendGrid requires me to define sender and that's impossible because I'd like to customer fill form with his email, etc so I would get this data on my inbox. Is it even possible with SendGrid or maybe there's other tool that would fit me better?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

what I have implemented in the past was a solution where the application sends an email to it self, and the email address of the user was added to the email header `reply-to`, this way whenever somebody with the access to the email client would press the Reply button, the user's mail would be the destination.

Example:

`admin@yoursystem.com` ---> Sends an email to ---> `admin@yoursystem.com` (with the user's message and his email address in the mail header `reply-to`).